# Exhausted available authentication methods (PhpStorm 2019.3)

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, phpstorm

When I try to check the SFTP connection, I get the following error

[image]

There were no changes on the server.

The problem appeared after reinstalling the system (Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Alexandr. I assume the reinstall is on the client side? The error looks like password authentication for SFTP is disabled for some unknown reason. Have you tried perhaps using a public/private key pair instead?

Comment: I may mean different thing, even a wrong password. Check IDE logs for possible hints: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files. may need to enable extra logging to see more details (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs)

Comment: The tickets that I found are either fixed or no replies from reporters: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%22Exhausted%20available%20authentication%20methods%22. If you cannot find your reason for such message, feel free to make a new ticket and provide your detailed logs there.

Comment: @Francis Thanks for the tip! Now I am using a key pair and the connection works fine!